# Calculus Exponential Function Help

Tags: calculus

I need help finding the limit of this expression.

I do not want the answer, I want to learn the steps to approach this problem.

$$\lim_{x \to\infty} 1.082^x$$

I know if $a > 1$, the limit is infinity if x is just approaching infinity from both sides and is 0 if x approaches infinity from the left.

Comment: Try evaluate it using:$$e^{\lim_{x \to\infty} ln( 1.082^x)}$$

Comment: Well, I'm being dumb... Figured out the answer from my own writing...

Answer (score 1):

To show that the limit is is infinity, you need to show that, for large enough x, the value is greater than any specified number.

In this case you can use Bernoulli's inequality
$(1+z)^n > 1+nz$ for 
$z\gt 0$ and $n > 1$.